# Compass - Showing direction based on latitude and longitude

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

In WP7, is it possible to show compass direction based on the given latitude and longitude values. (For example, if I am in India and if the latitude and longitude values of a place in some other country is given). If yes, please give some idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you worked out the geometry to calculate the bearing? Have you looked at the [how-to article about using the compass on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202974(v=vs.92))?

Comment: A compass would show North but you're talking about multiple places (India and "some other country") what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Matt Legacy : I wanted to know whether it is possible to show direction to a place(from my current location whether it is in north, south, etc,...) for which the latitude and longitude is given.

Comment: Of course it's possible to draw an arrow pointing from one location towards the direction (bearing) of another. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is known as the [Second (inverse) geodetic problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Second_.28inverse.29_geodetic_problem).

> "Given two points, determine the azimuth and length of the line
>   (straight line, arc or geodesic) that connects them." Wikipedia

You can get the distance using [System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Otherwise have a look at the excellent [C# Geodesy Library for GPS – Vincenty’s Formulae](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula/). In particular the GeodeticCurve.